# cucumber & protractor test, on Feature file, Error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token, expected ;

Tags: protractor, automated-tests, cucumber

[TO CHECK MY FEATURE FILE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hoxXD.png)  I'm new in Cucumber/Protractor. I have this error launching my `protractor.conf.js`:

```
E/launcher - Error: SyntaxError: C:/Users/home/Desktop/testing_protractor/test reali/login_1/features/test.feature: Unexpected token, expected ; (1:16)

1 | Feature: Verify the login page as UK customer
    |                 ^   2 |   As I am a UK customer   3 |   I want to open the login page   4 |   So that I can see the login page content and go to my-cart page
    at Parser.pp$5.raise (C:\Users\home\Desktop\testing_protractor\test reali\login_1\node_modules\babylon\lib\index.js:4454:13)
    at Parser.pp.unexpected (C:\Users\home\Desktop\testing_protractor\test reali\login_1\node_modules\babylon\lib\index.js:1761:8)
    at Parser.pp.semicolon (C:\Users\home\Desktop\testing_protractor\test reali\login_1\node_modules\babylon\lib\index.js:1742:38)
    at Parser.pp$1.parseExpressionStatement (C:\Users\home\Desktop\testing_protractor\test reali\login_1\node_modules\babylon\lib\index.js:2236:8)
    at Parser.pp$1.parseStatement (C:\Users\home\Desktop\testing_protractor\test reali\login_1\node_modules\babylon\lib\index.js:1911:17)
    at Parser.pp$1.parseLabeledStatement (C:\Users\home\Desktop\testing_protractor\test reali\login_1\node_modules\babylon\lib\index.js:2228:20)
    at Parser.pp$1.parseStatement (C:\Users\home\Desktop\testing_protractor\test reali\login_1\node_modules\babylon\lib\index.js:1909:17)
    at Parser.pp$1.parseBlockBody (C:\Users\home\Desktop\testing_protractor\test reali\login_1\node_modules\babylon\lib\index.js:2268:21)
    at Parser.pp$1.parseTopLevel (C:\Users\home\Desktop\testing_protractor\test reali\login_1\node_modules\babylon\lib\index.js:1778:8)
    at Parser.parse (C:\Users\home\Desktop\testing_protractor\test reali\login_1\node_modules\babylon\lib\index.js:1673:17) [15:04:28] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 100
```

Can u help me to solve this? Thank you!

Feature: Verify the login page as UK customer
    As I am a UK customer
    I want to open the login page
    So that I can see the login page content and go to my-cart page

Scenario: Verify the login page submit functionality as a UK registered customer
    Given I am a UK customer
    When I see the submit-button
        And I filled all the mandatory fields
    Then I am able to click on it to login
        And I am able to open MyCart page

Comment: Go to your file which is: features/test.feature, then see the feature with name: Verify the login page as UK customer. 
You have: "SyntaxError".

Comment: Show the entire content of file: `test.feature`

Comment: I added a screen of my feature file on the text of the question. Thank you

Comment: Please add the feature file content in your question with its original format, not in comment here.

Comment: Yes, i added a screen of the feature file on the question.

Comment: Why not add the content as you add the error message,  Screenshot is not a good way to show code.  And I think I find your issue please put  all words for `Feature` into one line, seems you break into multiple lines.    For quick verify, you can change to `Feature: aaa`, then run again.

Comment: I added the content on the question and changed "Feature: aaa".
Now the content of the feature file is:
Feature: aaa

Scenario: Verify the login page submit functionality as a UK registered customer
 Given I am a UK customer
 When I see the submit-button
  And I filled all the mandatory fields
 Then I am able to click on it to login
  And I am able to open MyCart page.

Comment: The error is the same:

The error is the same: 

E/launcher - Error: C:\Users\home\Desktop\testing_protractor\test reali\login_1\features\test.feature:3
Scenario: Verify the login page submit functionality as a UK registered customer
                 ^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at new Script (vm.js:51:7)
    at createScript (vm.js:138:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:199:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:624:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:671:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:573:32)
    (...)

Comment: That does not look like the same error to me. Why not update your question with the relevant code and error, in a decent format? This will help us help you, and you will get a better answer.